# Solr highlight somes html characters

Tags: html, solr, character, highlight

I have a problem with solr highlight component. In fact, when i search the word "eau", solr highlight component returns me :

```
<em>l&#</em>8217;Eau
```

But "eau" should be highlighted. I use the standart configuration of solr 3.3.

Thanks.

Comment: I upgrade to solr 3.4 but it changes nothing. I try to remove html encoder(solrconfig.xml) but it the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and as a workaround, I changed the characters that were being wrapped around the highlight, using the `hl.simple.pre` and `hl.simple.post` highlighting options to set the new values. I used a | (pipe character). Once I did this, the highlighting started working properly. So I then only had to add some additional processing to the results to replace the pipe back to the `<em>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for your response but it changes nothing. I always have the problem.